# Can a bot use the "Warnings" command of YAGPDB:xyz

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I would like for my bot (being coded with discord.py) to warn someone via YAGPDB.xyz if I type a command.

The Idea just popped into my head and I am stuck with this, the command works perfectly but it doesn't warn them. I don0t know if a bot can't use the warning command or it's another issue.

This is my code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("ADMIN")
async def w(ctx, person, reason="No usar el canal correcto"):
    await bot.get_channel(ach).send(f"""-warn {person} {reason}""")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(f"""{ctx.author.mention} Le he warneado :)""")
    await bot.get_channel(ach).send(f"""-warnings {person}""")
    time.sleep(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its almost certainly because YAGPDB.xyz ignores commands from other bots